# jquery tooltip not getting displayed

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am trying to create a tooltip as mentioned in the tutorial

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.htm

Here is my code snippet http://jsfiddle.net/wlogeshwaran/9XX3B/
It is not working . Please tell me where I am making the mistake .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually download and/or link to the ***[jQueryTOOLS](http://jquerytools.org/download/)***.

I've updated your ***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XX3B/5/)*** to show you a working example.

***EDIT: I also had to link to their stylesheet for their nice looking tips***

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9XX3B/4/

You have to include the library (http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js) and the function is tooltip **not** toolTip :)